VSCode keeping track of line ranges
I'm coming from neovim background and in neovim plugin development there is an API to create markers known as extmarks that automatically tracks text changes on the buffer. Therefore, we can create an extmark for a line range that we are interested in which assigns an id for it, and whenever we want to know the upto date line range after an edit on the buffer we can simply query back with that id
Is there a similar API provided by VSCode extension development API as well?
